# How do I evaluate a tuple based on multiple values inside that same tuple?

Tags: python-3.x

**How can I exclude certain tuples from being written to a file?**

I found a useful program that would let me create my own wordlist based on certain characters and a chosen wordlength range.
The program creates tuples and write them to a file via a for-loop.

Below is a snippet of the program.

```
import itertools

char = 'qwer'
output_file = 'Question4Stack.txt'

wordList = open(output_file, 'a')
for i in range(len(char), (len(char) + 1)):
    for xt in itertools.product(char, repeat=i):
        # xt retuns a tuple. Some of which I want to skip with continue.
        wordList.write(''.join(xt) + '\n')
wordList.close()

print("\nDone Sucessfully")
```

I want the program to be able to skip certain tuples
in which there are 3 or more of the same character present.

Outcome of snippet: (Before writing to a file)

```
1. ('q','q','q','q')
2. ('q','q','q','w')
3. ('q','q','q','e')
4. ('q','q','q','r')
5. ('q','q','w','q')
6. ('q','q','w','w')
7. ('q','q','w','e')
8. ('q','q','w','r')
```

How to skip tuple 1 - 4 in the for-loop?

Comment: Related: [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2600191/4518341)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What particular problem do you need help with to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Counter` to get the maximum number of the same character in the tuple. Then just continue without writing if it's more than 2.

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter

char = 'qwer'
output_file = 'Question4Stack.txt'

wordList = open(output_file, 'a')
for i in range(len(char), (len(char) + 1)):
    for xt in itertools.product(char, repeat=i):
        cnt = Counter(xt)
        if max(cnt.values()) > 2:
            continue
        # xt retuns a tuple. Some of which I want to skip with continue.
        wordList.write(''.join(xt) + '\n')
wordList.close()

print("\nDone Sucessfully")
```

**EDIT:** This is for only counting consecutive characters as a group

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter

char = 'qwer'
output_file = 'Question4Stack.txt'

wordList = open(output_file, 'a')
for i in range(len(char), (len(char) + 1)):
    for xt in itertools.product(char, repeat=i):
        cnts = [sum(1 for i in grp[1]) for grp in itertools.groupby(xt)]
        if max(cnts) > 2:
            continue
        # xt retuns a tuple. Some of which I want to skip with continue.
        wordList.write(''.join(xt) + '\n')
wordList.close()

print("\nDone Sucessfully")
```

Comment: That is a great solution! But what if you want to include tuples like: `('q','w',q,'e')`?

Comment: That tuple would be included, because it has less than 3 as the max value in the counter.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry. I wanted to edit my previous comment but I was to late to correct my mistake.
And what if you only want to exclude tuples which has sequential characters in them like: `('q','q','q','e')`?

Comment: Thank you, PyPingu! That is exactly what I need. Plus I'm deep diving in the Itertools Module. Thank you so much for you time and help. Grt, M

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

char = 'qwer'
output_file = 'Question4Stack.txt'

wordList = open(output_file, 'a')
for i in range(len(char), (len(char) + 1)):
    for xt in itertools.product(char, repeat=i):
        if pd.Series(xt).value_counts().max() < 3:
            # xt retuns a tuple. Some of which I want to skip with continue.
            print(xt)
            wordList.write(''.join(xt) + '\n')
wordList.close()

print("\nDone Sucessfully")
```